# Xampp Stylesheet problems don't know why

Tags: html, css, xampp

Hey i started xampp project and all works fine just the css not. It doesnt show me any modififaction of my stylesheet i normaly don't work with xampp i don't know what i did wrong
I have an Header that I include on evry page but it doesn't take the css

```
head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/reset.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
```

Normaly it should work but i can't know why not allready tested to make a fix link but didn't work 
Thank for Help in advance :)

 Sry for my English :/

Comment: It's not related to XAMPP. There's a mistake in the markup, the closing parenthesis at the end of `href` caused the problem.

Comment: Sry it was an error on putting code here it isn't in my code but it's not that

Comment: Maybe use a relative path?

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css" />

Comment: @user1758777 i use absolute paths